# Plot stacked histogram with grouped DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, plot, histogram, visualization

I want I stacked histogram where the different classes are visible.

At the moment I have the histogram without classes with this code:

```
plt.hist(hist_matrix2.column_name)
```

which produces this histogram:

[image: histogram without classes]

and another histogram with the same data, that is grouped by the classes with this code:

```
hist_matrix2.groupby("number").column_name.plot.hist(alpha=0.5, bins  = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30], stacked = True)
```

which produces this histogram:

[image: histogram with classes]

As you can see the classes are there but it is not stacked, although the parameter is set. What can I do to stack the classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plt.hist has a built-in stacking flag you can set:

```
plt.hist(hist_matrix2.column_name, stacked=True)
```

Edit in response to your question, for long data (with multiple levels stacked) first you need to restructure the data into a list of lists:

```
wide=hist_matrix2.pivot( columns='number', values='column_name')
#This creates many missing values which pandas does not like, so we drop them
widelist=[wide[col].dropna() for col in wide.columns]
# and the stacked graph is here
plt.hist(widelist,stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: But that is not seperated by classes. This stacking just works if your classes are seperated by columns. In my case in the column 'number'  is the class label. With the groupby i get the seperated classes but they are overlaying and i want them stacked (plot2).